# Execution is reverted in Solidity and Remix

Tags: solidity, remix

I've wrote a simple code for fetching ETH price by using *Chainlink* interfaces as below:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.6.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract ABI {

    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

    constructor() public {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0xF4030086522a5bEEa4988F8cA5B36dbC97BeE88c);
    }

    function latestPrice() public view returns (int256) {
        (, int256 answer,,,) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return answer;
    }

}
```

The problem is when is being compiled by Remix, it has no problem but after execution it throws the error below:

**call to `ContractName`.`FunctionName` errored: execution reverted**

Do you think what the problem is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `ENVIRONMENT` to `Injected Web3` in Remix IDE and connect to `metamask`. For example, if you are using `Kovan` network use address as mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/get-the-latest-price/).

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract PriceConsumerV3 {

    AggregatorV3Interface internal priceFeed;

    /**
     * Network: Kovan
     * Aggregator: ETH/USD
     * Address: 0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331
     */
    constructor() {
        priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(0x9326BFA02ADD2366b30bacB125260Af641031331);
    }

    /**
     * Returns the latest price
     */
    function getLatestPrice() public view returns (int) {
        (
            /*uint80 roundID*/,
            int price,
            /*uint startedAt*/,
            /*uint timeStamp*/,
            /*uint80 answeredInRound*/
        ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
        return price;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your question didn't specify on which network you're running the script, I'm assuming that you're using the Remix VM emulator.

The specified Chainlink [contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0xF4030086522a5bEEa4988F8cA5B36dbC97BeE88c) is available on Ethereum mainnet only. Any other network (including the emulator) does not have this contract deployed on this address.

To use the data feed contract in Remix, you can create a local fork of the mainnet, and then connect to the local network in the IDE.